# java access public class method without creating object

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and I have a Drink class where I have a method showAll() to print all my drink objects that are stored in a private hashset . In my main function I can have access to this method by saying

```
Drink test = new Drink(value1 , value2 , ....);
test.showAll();
```

Is there a way to access my showAll() method without creating an object as I just want to print all the array objects without the need to create a new object each time I want to print

Drink.java

```
private static HashSet<Drink> drinks = new HashSet(); //store all drinks in hashset 

  public void AddDrink(Drink d ){ //add a drink 
     try {
          drinks.add(d);
     }catch(Exception e ){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
  }
  
  public void showAll() {  //show all drinks 
      for(Drink d : drinks) {
          System.out.println(d);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the method showAll():

```
  public void showAll() {  //show all drinks 
      for(Drink d : drinks) {
          System.out.println(d);
      }
```

the only field (*i.e.,* drinks) data that you are using is also static:

```
private static HashSet<Drink> drinks = new HashSet(); //store all drinks in hashset
```

you can turn your method into static:

```
public void static showAll(){...}
```

Then you can call that method as `Drink.showAll()`. Btw you can shorten your showAll method from:

```
  public void showAll() {  //show all drinks 
      for(Drink d : drinks) {
          System.out.println(d);
      }
  }
```

to just:

```
   public static void showAll() {
        drinks.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

by combining `forEach` with `method reference`.

In your current design, `public void AddDrink(Drink d )` can also be turn into static method as well (i.e., `public static void AddDrink(Drink d )`.

That all being said, a better design for your class has been proposed on the comments by @JustAnotherDeveloper